# How do I reverse the `cases` function?

Tags: typst

I would like to do the opposite of `cases`. Instead of this:
[image: cases]
(which is given by `$ f(x) = cases(g(x), h(x)) $`)

I want this:
[image: sesac]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by creating the following function:

```
#let sesac(..arr, spacing: 6pt) = {
  box($ lr(#stack(dir: ttb, spacing: spacing, ..arr.pos().map(item => align(left, $ #item $))) }) $, )
}
```

and using it like so:
`$ sesac(g(x), h(x)) = f(x) $)`

to get
[image: sesac]

I called it "sesac", since that's "cases" spelled backwards.

In the case where you need to align the equations on the left (or right) side, I also made `sesac2`:
`#let sesac2(l, r) = $ lr(#box(l) }) #box(r) $`

Used as follows:

```
#sesac2($ g(x) \
          h(x) $, $ f(x) $)
```

(It produces very similar output)